# What happens if you don't pay your bills?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I was waiting out a bounty watching the TV in my apartment when I saw a message box in the corner pop up saying that $75 was deducted from my in-game bank account for daily utilities and maintenance.  I got hit for another $50 for my garage as well.

**First off, how often does this happen?**  Per day in game, per day in real life, per day in-game so long as you spend time in the apartment?  I don't want to spend a week or two not playing the game to find my bank account has been drained.  If I'm getting this for every in-game day that's $10,500 for a week in real time.

**Second, what happens if you can't pay?** Do you lose the apartment? Are you locked out of it? Do they shut off your water and power?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What If found out so far:

**how often does this happen?**

It happens per in-game day (48 minutes). You have to pay it, even if you haven't been in your apartment.

You only need to pay, if you are playing GTA Online.

**what happens if you can't pay?**

You don't lose the apartment and you don't get locked out.
What they do - They shut off your water and power, so you can't watch TV, use the radio or shower.

If you can't pay the mechanic, he won't answer your phone when you call him, so he won't bring you a car.

Comment: You can't use the radio either, lol :)

Comment: Figuring out if you have to pay while your're not online is the big part.

Comment: I haven't tested specifically but I'm 99% sure that you do not have to pay for time spent offline. I haven't noticed any accruing charges from my garage and that would make less than zero sense from a game design perspective. Otherwise.... haven't played in a week? Well no point in playing ever again because all of my money is gone.

Comment: @CaulynDarr - Indeed. I can verify or debunk it, once I'm home.

Comment: @5pike: You know what happend with the garage / the mechanic if you can't pay this stuff?

Comment: @dTDesign - I'll ad it to the answer